# VSCode auto-indent closing tag to match opening tag indentation

Tags: visual-studio-code

I recently reinstalled vscode and lost all of my configurations... sad day.

Prior to this day, I had some setting or extension that automatically decreased the indent of my closing tag to match that of the opening tag (or simply decreased the indent one level from the previous closing tag). Basically, it automatically does what I accomplish in this screenshot by pressing `shift-tab`:

[image]

What am I forgetting? Thanks in advance. Also, apologies in advance for the slowest gif of a keyboard shortcut I've ever witnessed.